# Image smoothing with own smoothing function

Tags: performance-tuning, image-processing

I have thousands images similar to the following one:

[image]
This `image` was produced with the following color table:

```
colTable = {{Black}, 
   Table[{Blend[{Blue, Green, Yellow, Red}, x]}, {x, 1/255, 1, 
     1/255}]};
colTable = Flatten[colTable];
...
image = 
 Colorize[Image[image], ColorFunction -> (Blend[colTable, #] &)]
```

Now I would like to smooth this image pixel by pixel following a defined function.

The idea behind the smoothing is: 
I want to calculate around each pixel the number of black pixels plus the number of red pixels in a defined sourrounding rectangle (e.g. rectangle size: `dx=dy=40 pixels`). This number value is devided by the number of rectangle pixels and the final value determines a certain smoothed color for the corresponding pixel.

The code which I wrote is the following:

```
dim = ImageDimensions[image];

sx = dim[[1]];
sy = dim[[2]];

dx = 40;
dy = 40;

smoothImage = ConstantArray[0, {sx, sy}];

Table[

 Table[

   subImage = 
    ImageTake[
     image, {iy - dy/2, iy + dy/2 - 1}, {ix - dx/2, ix + dx/2 - 1}];
   data = ImageData[subImage];
   sumRB = 
    Count[data, {0., 0., 0.}, Infinity] + 
     Count[data, {1., 0., 0.}, Infinity];
   smoothValues[[ix, iy]] = sumRB/(dx*dy);

   , {ix, dx/2 + 1, sx - dx/2 + 1}

   ];

 , {iy, dy/2 + 1, sy - dy/2 + 1}

 ]

max = Max[smoothValues];

smoothImage = Image[smoothValue/max];
smoothImage = 
 Colorize[Image[smoothImage], ColorFunction -> (Blend[colTable, #] &)]
```

The problem is: this code is extremely slow and lasts for hours (only for one image) ... it might also be I made somewhere a mistake ...

Is there another way (e.g. by compilation, parallel processing, cuda or any other fast routines) to solve this problem?

My expectation is to get such a smoothed image depending on the color table and the used color range (this image I have produced with IDL which takes 1 sec).

[image]

Comment: Why don't you process the source image (before the `Colorize` step) - wouldn't that make the counting easier?

Comment: could you not use `ImageFilter` ? also `ParallelTable` would be a quick way to parallelize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you're only counting/summing pixel values in a sliding window, you don't have to recalculate the whole sum for every pixel. You can just "count" red/black pixels in a "1x1 window" and then use a moving average or "box" filter to sum over neighborhoods.

First calculate two images where every red/black pixel is 1, other pixels 0:

```
image = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pgppv.png"]
dx = 40;
dy = 40;

red = {1, 0, 0};
black = {0, 0, 0};
redPixels = 
  Binarize[ColorNegate@ImageApply[Norm[# - red] &, image], 10^-5];
blackPixels = 
  Binarize[ColorNegate@ImageApply[Norm[# - black] &, image], 10^-5];
```

Then apply a box filter to those images and add them:

```
box = BoxMatrix[Floor[{dx, dy}/2]];
ImageAdd[ImageConvolve[redPixels, box], 
  ImageConvolve[blackPixels, box]] // ImageAdjust
```

[image]

Comment: `Norm[# - {0, 0, 0}] &` is the same as plain `Norm`, no?

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I wanted to make the step from `Count[data, {0., 0., 0.}, Infinity]` to `Norm[# - {0,0,0}]` more obvious.

Comment: Ah, of course; more illustrative that way. :)

Comment: @nikie: great and fast.  thanks a lot.
How would the code look like for a circular filter with a certain radius r?

Comment: @mrz: You would simply use `DiskMatrix` instead of `BoxMatrix`

Comment: @nikie: thanks as lot for your help

Comment: @nikie: dear nikie, since your solution was excellent, I would like to ask you to have a look on the following problem (is related to the input file you helped me to smooth): http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87795/visualization-of-mean-movement-of-objects

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ColorReplace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorReplace.html):

```
image = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pgppv.png"];
dx = 40;
dy = 40;
redblack = 
 ColorReplace[image, {Red -> White, Black -> White, _ -> Black}];
box = BoxMatrix[Floor[{dx, dy}/2]];
ImageAdjust[ImageConvolve[redblack, box]]
```

[image: filtered image]

Comment: very interesting and helpful ... thanks for the help.